# How to resolve the error "make[1]: *** No rule to make target `init/main.o', needed by ***" in Linux building process?

Tags: linux, build, makefile

I tried to build the kernel for "RHEL: 2.6.18.128-el5" version. I installed the source rpm files also using $rpm -ivh 2.6.18.128-el5.src.rpm
Though it showed some warnings, i thought it got installed properly. Then i tried

```
$ cd /usr/src/redhat/SPECS ; rpmbuild -bp kernel*spec
```

and it copied all patch files in source.
Then, i started the process as follows:

```
[root@localhost 2.6.18-128.el5-i686]# make menuconfig
scripts/kconfig/mconf arch/i386/Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .VVV
#
#
# configuration written to .config
#


*** End of Linux kernel configuration.
*** Execute 'make' to build the kernel or try 'make help'.

[root@localhost 2.6.18-128.el5-i686]# make
scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/i386/Kconfig
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `init/main.o', needed by `init/built-in.o'.  Stop.
make: *** [init] Error 2
```

Can anybody share the details about "where is the error get caught in the procedure and how to rectify it ?

Answer (score 1):

this is because some file is missing and the rule is written for that missing file in the makefile. 
its not able to find main.o needed by built-in.o that means some file like main.cpp is missing and so the rule for main.cpp to main.o in makefile is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing `make bzImage` or `make modules` instead of a pure `make`?

Check [this post](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=403).